# How to identify the source file of an icon in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, icons, retina, dired

My Emacs icons for files etc. are blurry on my MB Air M1 laptop using an external 4k display. Here is an example from Treemacs, but it is the same in Dired:

[image]

As you can see, the fonts are ok, but icons are blurry.

How to identify the source file for the icon? Is there something like C-h and then something to show the icon file path so I can replace it for something that is compatible with 4k resolution?

Comment: My `dired` does not show icons at all, so I suspect you use some external package to do that: what package is that?

Comment: Since you're on a Mac, Emacs's icons are under Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/images. Package icons will be in the individual package directories. For instance, for my version treemacs the icons are in treemacs-20220801.1910/icons.